# Notification Light

Tags: notifications, htc-8s

I have a HTC phone and I don't have a notification light on my phone. I've seen it inother windows phones, I want to know if I can get it or set it or whatever. Do you guys know if my phone can have a notification light? In an update or something?

Comment: Which HTC phone is it?

Comment: HTC windows phone 8S

Comment: Helo Marta. The thing you are trying to find is very Android-sh. In Windows Phone I don't remember an OEM using it. The only one is HTC 8X that has notification light for charging and charged.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on the hardware I think. I'm using the Nokia Lumia 920, there's no notification light on my phone as well even I'm updated to Windows Phone 8.1. On the other hand, the Nokia Lumia 925 have the notification light since Windows Phone 8, so I think is depends on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of a notification light on [the HTC specs](http://www.htc.com/uk/smartphones/htc-wp-8s/#section-5-0), so your options would be to change phone, either to a phone that has a light, or take a look at some of the newer phones that support the Glance screen option (which, in my opinion, is way better than a little light :)